# How can I get first 4 of the childrens and wrap it into the div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I find first 4 children of the parent and wrap it into div, then next 4 and so on? Google does not know! :(

FROM:

```
<div class="main">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
</div>
```

TO:

```
<div lass="main">
    <div class="pack1">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
    </div>

    <div class="pack1">
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help much appreciated.

I can find first 4 by: `$('.main > div:lt(4)').wrapAll('<div class="pack1"></div>');`
But how to get every 4??

Pete

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not the most elegant way but its working.

```
var sel;
while ( (sel = $('.main > div:not(.pack1)')).length > 0 )
{
    sel.slice(0,4).wrapAll('<div class="pack1"></div>');
}
```

Here a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5chaL/3/).

## Update

Here with counter for the class. We have to use a 2nd class `pack` for the exclude of all packed divs.

```
var sel;
var count = 1;
while ( (sel = $('.main > div:not(.pack)')).length > 0 )
{
    sel.slice(0,4).wrapAll('<div class="pack pack'+ count++ +'"></div>');
}
```

And the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5chaL/4/)

Or we go with

```
var sel;
var count = 1;
while ( (sel = $('.main > div:not([class^="pack"])')).length > 0 )
{
    sel.slice(0,4).wrapAll('<div class="pack'+ count++ +'"></div>');
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5chaL/5/) for that.

Comment: In his example he uses "pack1" for both groups, so i did not add the counter intentionally ;-)

Comment: @DanielB - (+1) increasing would be perfect!

Comment: @Pete, This makes it a bit more complicated, because of the selection with `:not(class)`. I'll make an update

Comment: @DanielB - here is what I'm trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/NAL8E/ - filter + paggination. At the moment my paggination reseting my filtering (hiding all divs). Just thinking, would be easier find visible divs in order e.g form 0- 4, 4-8 etc.. What do you think? Please note at this stage paggination does not work!

Comment: @DanielB Simple hide/ show will not work with both filtering & pagination - using some  class .with-filter would be necessary - what do you think?

Comment: I made your pagination work in this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NAL8E/7/)

Answer (score 0):

this is just an idea ( and im not sure i coded it right ), but you could use this method.

```
   var first = $(".main div:lt(4)");
    $(".main div:lt(4)").remove();
    var second = $(".main div:lt(4)");
    $(".main div:lt(4)").remove();

    $(".main").append("<div class=pack1>" + first+ "</div>");
    $(".main").append("<div class=pack2>" + second+ "</div>");
```